# Can't Add More Than 10 Items to View SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm finishing an app that needs user data entry fields. I modeled it with a small number of data elements to streamline the development. Today I attempted to add additional elements and was astounded to find that I could only add 10 views to a view. So I tried the simplest of designs (below). If I added 11 "things" to the view it immediately presented the error on the top item, whatever it was:

"Argument passed to call that takes no arguments"

Doesn't matter whether I call the outside container a ScrollView, VStack, List or Form. Same behavior. Doesn't matter whether the Text/TextField sub units are in a VStack or not.

So I went back to basics - just added ten Text views. No problem. Add an eleventh and it blows up. Here's one of the variants - but all I need to do was add 10 simple Text views to get it to break.

I must be missing something really basic here. I checked for a newer release of Xcodebut I have Version 11.2 beta 2 (11B44), the latest.

```
@State private var textField1: String = "Pass to the ListCell"
@State private var textField2: String = "2"
//more of these


var body: some View {

    NavigationView {
        VStack {

            //extract the VStack and create a separate struct
            ListCell(tfString: textField1)

            VStack {
                Text("Text Field")
                TextField("Placeholder", text: $textField2)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .padding()
            }

            VStack {
                Text("Text Field")
                TextField("Placeholder", text: $textField3)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .padding()
            }

            //more of the above VStacks

            Text("6")
            Text("7")
            Text("8")
            Text("9")
            Text("10")
            //Spacer()
            //Text("11")
        }
    }
}
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Just for fun, this is the actual reason: https://twitter.com/rockthebruno/status/1194225536949792769

Comment: Very interesting. A good read.

Comment: ```10 is the max amount of subviews you can have in SwiftUI```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use `Group {...}` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/group

```
var body: some View {

    NavigationView {
        VStack {

            //extract the VStack and create a separate struct
            ListCell(tfString: textField1)
            Group {
                VStack {
                    Text("Text Field")
                    TextField("Placeholder", text: $textField2)
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                        .padding()
                }

                VStack {
                    Text("Text Field")
                    TextField("Placeholder", text: $textField3)
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                        .padding()
                }
            }

            //more of the above VStacks
            Group {
                Text("6")
                Text("7")
                Text("8")
                Text("9")
                Text("10")
            }
            //Spacer()
            //Text("11")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`ViewBuilder`s in SwiftUI take between 0 and 10 elements into their initializer anything more than that and you have to start grouping them using `Group`, `VStack`, `HStack`, `List`, `ForEach` and so on.

The best approach is to start extracting a few elements that belong together into separate Views, for example:

```
struct FormCell: View {

    @Binding var inputString: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Text Field")
            TextField("Placeholder", text: $inputString)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Next if you have a few of them, you can group them using `ForEach` and `List` or `VStack`.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Group` as people suggest.

However, you can extend `ViewBuilder` to make builders for more than 10 views. I created an article that walk you through it at [**More than 10 views in SwiftUI** extending ViewBuilder](http://blog.eppz.eu/more-than-10-views-in-swiftui/).

[image]